# Python: How to pass output of the map function as arguments

Tags: python, dictionary, zip, repeat, python-itertools

I need to pass some arguments to the `starmap_async` function. I have a list `my_list` that has different values in it and some constants that are repeated. I have a way to pass the arguments as bellow:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import repeat

def f(a,b,c,d):
    return (a,b,c,d)

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

with mp.Pool(cpu_num) as pool:
    res = pool.starmap_async(f, zip(my_list, repeat(a),repeat(b),repeat(c),repeat(d)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    res.get()
```

It works and generates arguments like this which is the desired output:

```
(1,a,b,c,d)
(2,a,b,c,d)
(3,a,b,c,d)
(4,a,b,c,d)
(5,a,b,c,d)
```

Now I want to use the `map` function to do something like this:

```
res = pool.starmap_async(f, zip(my_list, repeat(list(map(repeat, 
[a, b, c, d])))))
```

but then I end up with arguments like this:

```
(1,(a,b,c,d))
(2,(a,b,c,d))
(3,(a,b,c,d))
(4,(a,b,c,d))
(5,(a,b,c,d))
```

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: what result do you want?

Comment: the first version: (1,a,b,c,d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from itertools import repeat

def f(a,b,c,d):
    return (a,b,c,d)

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

with mp.Pool(cpu_num) as pool:
    res = pool.starmap_async(f, zip(my_list, *map(repeat, (a,b,c,d))))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    res.get()
```